# Test mode won't turn off windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I can't turn off test mode in Windows 10 ;( After some driver development, It is just stuck. `bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON` didn't help. After several restarts, this message remains. - https://prnt.sc/uh7sse

Comment: Can you start in Safe Mode and the update your drivers to newest Microsoft signed drivers?

Comment: Did you remove the unsigned drivers? Do you want to end Testmode or just remove the Watermark?